# Restoring data from badly damaged HDD

Tags: hard-drive, restore

There is a message in `Disks`: **DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON**

I have no idea what happed to this HDD.

I tried to make an image of the damaged partition using `Disks` but after coping 15GB of the partition I already had 2GB of reading errors! And copy time increased to 2 weeks.

When I am trying to copy with `dd` then:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb2 conv=sync,noerror bs=64K status=progress | gzip -c > /media/zentala/Biblioteka/lenovo2tb.image.gz
5177344 bytes (5,2 MB, 4,9 MiB) copied, 3 s, 1,5 MB/s
dd: error reading '/dev/sdb2': Input/output error
78+1 records in
79+0 records out
5177344 bytes (5,2 MB, 4,9 MiB) copied, 6,51588 s, 795 kB/s
5177344 bytes (5,2 MB, 4,9 MiB) copied, 7 s, 795 kB/s
dd: error reading '/dev/sdb2': Input/output error
78+1 records in
79+0 records out
5177344 bytes (5,2 MB, 4,9 MiB) copied, 9,62374 s, 538 kB/s
5177344 bytes (5,2 MB, 4,9 MiB) copied, 10 s, 538 kB/s
dd: error reading '/dev/sdb2': Input/output error
78+1 records in
79+0 records out
............................
```

The question is: ***is there any option on how to retrieve data from this drive...?*** And what happened to it?

Logs from `smartctl` bellow.

```
$ sudo smartctl -x /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-54-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD20SPZX-00UA7T0
Serial Number:    WD-WX61E28EYKTV
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 65e257702
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    2 000 398 934 016 bytes [2,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Nov 21 15:20:43 2020 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM level is:     254 (maximum performance)
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
ATA Security is:  Disabled, frozen [SEC2]
Wt Cache Reorder: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (10920) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x71) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 238) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR-K   029   029   051    NOW  8757
  3 Spin_Up_Time            POS--K   223   217   021    -    1833
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   096   096   000    -    4391
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   197   197   140    -    8752
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         -OSR-K   200   199   000    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   095   095   000    -    3872
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   099   099   000    -    1001
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   200   200   000    -    136
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--CK   197   197   000    -    10601
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   110   088   000    -    37
196 Reallocated_Event_Count -O--CK   016   016   000    -    184
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--CK   194   194   000    -    1955
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----CK   100   253   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--CK   200   200   000    -    0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   ---R--   100   253   000    -    0
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O      5  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      6  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  SATA NCQ Queued Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x24       GPL     R/O    288  Current Device Internal Status Data log
0x30       GPL,SL  R/O      9  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa0-0xa7  GPL,SL  VS      16  Device vendor specific log
0xa8-0xb6  GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xb7       GPL,SL  VS      76  Device vendor specific log
0xb9       GPL,SL  VS       4  Device vendor specific log
0xbd       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xc0       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xc1       GPL     VS      93  Device vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (6 sectors)
Device Error Count: 8121 (device log contains only the most recent 24 errors)
    CR     = Command Register
    FEATR  = Features Register
    COUNT  = Count (was: Sector Count) Register
    LBA_48 = Upper bytes of LBA High/Mid/Low Registers ]  ATA-8
    LH     = LBA High (was: Cylinder High) Register    ]   LBA
    LM     = LBA Mid (was: Cylinder Low) Register      ] Register
    LL     = LBA Low (was: Sector Number) Register     ]
    DV     = Device (was: Device/Head) Register
    DC     = Device Control Register
    ER     = Error register
    ST     = Status register
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 8121 [8] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3872 hours (161 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 01 c3 78 00 e1 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x01c37800 = 29587456

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  c8 00 00 00 08 00 00 01 c3 78 00 e1 08     03:09:43.161  READ DMA
  e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08     03:09:43.147  CHECK POWER MODE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:43.144  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:43.144  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:43.024  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 8120 [7] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3872 hours (161 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 01 c3 70 00 e1 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x01c37000 = 29585408

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  c8 00 00 00 08 00 00 01 c3 70 00 e1 08     03:09:40.032  READ DMA
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:40.012  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:40.012  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:39.887  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  c8 00 00 00 08 00 00 01 c3 68 00 e1 08     03:09:37.196  READ DMA

Error 8119 [6] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3872 hours (161 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 01 c3 68 00 e1 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x01c36800 = 29583360

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  c8 00 00 00 08 00 00 01 c3 68 00 e1 08     03:09:37.196  READ DMA
  e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08     03:09:37.187  CHECK POWER MODE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:37.182  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:37.182  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:37.058  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 8118 [5] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3872 hours (161 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 01 c3 60 00 e1 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x01c36000 = 29581312

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  c8 00 00 00 08 00 00 01 c3 60 00 e1 08     03:09:34.060  READ DMA
  e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08     03:09:34.048  CHECK POWER MODE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:34.046  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:34.046  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:33.917  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 8117 [4] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3872 hours (161 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 01 c3 58 00 e1 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x01c35800 = 29579264

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  c8 00 00 00 08 00 00 01 c3 58 00 e1 08     03:09:30.947  READ DMA
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:30.933  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:30.933  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:30.813  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  c8 00 00 00 08 00 00 01 c3 50 00 e1 08     03:09:28.140  READ DMA

Error 8116 [3] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3872 hours (161 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 01 c3 50 00 e1 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x01c35000 = 29577216

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  c8 00 00 00 08 00 00 01 c3 50 00 e1 08     03:09:28.140  READ DMA
  e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08     03:09:28.126  CHECK POWER MODE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:28.124  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:28.124  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:27.983  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 8115 [2] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3872 hours (161 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 01 c3 48 00 e1 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x01c34800 = 29575168

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  c8 00 00 00 08 00 00 01 c3 48 00 e1 08     03:09:25.312  READ DMA
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:25.293  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:25.292  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:25.166  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  c8 00 00 00 08 00 00 01 c3 40 00 e1 08     03:09:22.481  READ DMA

Error 8114 [1] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3872 hours (161 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 01 c3 40 00 e1 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x01c34000 = 29573120

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  c8 00 00 00 08 00 00 01 c3 40 00 e1 08     03:09:22.481  READ DMA
  e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08     03:09:22.468  CHECK POWER MODE
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:22.465  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 00 03 00 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:22.465  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a0 08     03:09:22.341  IDENTIFY DEVICE

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Aborted by host               70%      1499         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       258 (0x0102)
SCT Support Level:                   1
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    37 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     23/37 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     20/59 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0
Vendor specific:
01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         1 minute
Temperature Logging Interval:        1 minute
Min/Max recommended Temperature:      0/60 Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:           -41/85 Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    128 (23)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
  24    2020-11-21 13:13    37  ******************
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  ******************
  28    2020-11-21 13:17    37  ******************
  29    2020-11-21 13:18    36  *****************
 ...    ..( 33 skipped).    ..  *****************
  63    2020-11-21 13:52    36  *****************
  64    2020-11-21 13:53    35  ****************
 ...    ..( 19 skipped).    ..  ****************
  84    2020-11-21 14:13    35  ****************
  85    2020-11-21 14:14    36  *****************
 ...    ..( 16 skipped).    ..  *****************
 102    2020-11-21 14:31    36  *****************
 103    2020-11-21 14:32    35  ****************
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  ****************
 107    2020-11-21 14:36    35  ****************
 108    2020-11-21 14:37    36  *****************
 109    2020-11-21 14:38    35  ****************
 110    2020-11-21 14:39    35  ****************
 111    2020-11-21 14:40    35  ****************
 112    2020-11-21 14:41    36  *****************
 ...    ..( 35 skipped).    ..  *****************
  20    2020-11-21 15:17    36  *****************
  21    2020-11-21 15:18    37  ******************
  22    2020-11-21 15:19    37  ******************
  23    2020-11-21 15:20    37  ******************

SCT Error Recovery Control command not supported

Device Statistics (GP/SMART Log 0x04) not supported

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0002  2            0  R_ERR response for data FIS
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0005  2            0  R_ERR response for non-data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
0x0008  2            0  Device-to-host non-data FIS retries
0x0009  2            2  Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy
0x000a  2            3  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x000b  2            0  CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x000d  2            0  Non-CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x000f  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, CRC
0x0012  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, CRC
0x8000  4        11529  Vendor specific
```

Comment: One thing you might want to check is the data cable going to the HDD.  I have a server with a RAID5 in it, and one of my drives kept giving me grief and going offline out of the RAID array.  Turns out with SATA if you're not using locking cables they can come loose and give the impression of a drive going bad.  If it is tight or locked in, then yes, you are experiencing a drive failure.  Also, with backups, usually all that is needed is your `/home/username` folder as everything else can usually be reinstalled.

Comment: See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery and it suggests gddrescue. gddrescue better than ddrescue
http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html

Comment: Although it looks like the drive is toast, edit your question and show me `grep -i FPDMA /var/log/syslog*`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema It returns nothing.

Comment: Replace the drive.

Comment: @Terrance It's not about connection. I tried a few machines.

Comment: @PawelZentala It was just a suggestion.  You didn't mention any of that in your question.  Please, next time you ask a question add details that can help us.  We are not mind readers.  You have a bad drive then.

Answer (score 2):

There's not much you can do in this case if the drive is damaged. You can try to restore what's left on the device with `ddrescue`. This will take a long time and you might have to interrupt and restart this process a few times.

Comment: Thanks. I installed the GUI version and I am making an image from what left. How to retrieve those data from image?

Comment: You mount the file as a loopback device and by looking at the partition table inside the image file, you will have to use byte count where a partition starts and end as the offset, so the `mount` command knows at which position the partition inside the image starts and end.